# How do I perform weighted k-means clustering with normalized weights in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I want to explore spatial data---a bunch of (x,y) coordinates---along with the human population of each location.

Suppose we generate sample data with

```
set.seed(1337)    
x <- c(runif(25,0,33), runif(25, 33, 67), runif(25, 67, 100))
y <- c(runif(25,0,33), runif(25, 33, 67), runif(25, 67, 100))
coordinates <- scale(cbind(x,y))
weights <- scale(c( rep(5, 40), rep(2,35) ))
this_data <- data.frame(cbind(coordinates,weights))
colnames(this_data) <- c("x", "y", "weights")
```

then the data will look like

```
           x          y   weights
1 -1.2490708 -1.0839889 0.9291573
2 -0.8814155 -0.8601006 0.9291573
3 -1.5086446 -1.3284672 0.9291573
4 -1.1373619 -0.9263723 0.9291573
5 -0.6717665 -1.2870855 0.9291573
6 -1.1669900 -0.7871885 0.9291573
...
           x         y   weights
70 0.6288477 1.0054889 -1.061894
71 0.5050766 0.6968253 -1.061894
72 1.6129723 1.1435093 -1.061894
73 1.5478380 0.6823836 -1.061894
74 1.4146971 1.4278767 -1.061894
75 0.9271628 1.3399865 -1.061894
```

A simple application of kmeans() yields

```
fit <- kmeans(coordinates, 3)
plot(x,y, axes = FALSE, col = fit$cluster, pch = fit$cluster, xlab = "", ylab = "")
```

[image]

The population data can be in millions of people, so I do not want to do a frequency approach (i.e. replicating rows many times for "weight").  Is there a way that I can still incorporate that "weight" variable into k-means clustering?  That should get a different result than in the picture.

Comment: If you need help choosing a statistical clustering method that incorporates weights, you should be asking over at [stats.se] where statistical methods are on-topic. Right now this isn't really a specific programming question. Perhaps you could make it clear what the objective would be in clustering with your weights (ie what are the properties of the desired output).

Comment: Ok; thank you for the help

Comment: But avoid crossposting the exact same. At least try to make it more focused. I wouldnjt be surprised if CV  rejects it as too much programming involved... People can vote to migrate: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202943/how-do-i-perform-weighted-k-means-clustering-with-normalized-weights-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrating weight into k-means is trivial.

But I don't think the out-of-the-box versions in R support this, so you will have to write the code yourself. Beware that the R interpreter is really slow. The k-means function you are using is Fortran, and that is why it's so fast. `flexcluster` may support weights, but benchmark it to see how bad the performance is.